# Library for React Native Apps - Plain JS API Vs. Hooks based API

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I am going to develop a JS based library (SDK) which would be used by developers in their react native Apps. Does it make sense to model my APIs as plain POJO APIs (or) hooks?

Example API:
Promise getRapidProductInformation(RapidProductId);

Vs.

function useGetRapidProductInformation(RapidProductId) : { isLoading, serverError, apiData };

NOTE: In general, Developers would need to transform and collate some more data with my API response object. So I guess most of the developers' top level UI tsx file would not directly consume my APIs